# I am trying to have an MQTT protocol in android studio. I have also updated gradle.properties

Tags: java, android, mqtt, android-mqtt-client

For adding dependency, I added below code to project level gradle file

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
}
```

}

and at app level gradle file I added ,

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
```

}

Getting dependency resolution error: please find below the exception occurred.

> Duplicate class androidx.collection.LruCache found in modules collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NavUtils found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Builder found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat$IntentBuilder found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat$IntentReader found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.content.IntentCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.content.pm.ActivityInfoCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.database.DatabaseUtilsCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.util.DebugUtils found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.util.LogWriter found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.util.TimeUtils found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MenuCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MotionEventCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.VelocityTrackerCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewConfigurationCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewGroupCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEventCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat$AccessibilityStateChangeListenerCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.EdgeEffectCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter$ChangeObserver found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter$MyDataSetObserver found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter$CursorFilterClient found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$CursorToStringConverter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$ViewBinder found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackState found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackState$1 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$SavedState found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$SavedState$1 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$BackStackEntry found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$OnBackStackChangedListener found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$3 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$4 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$5 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState$1 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState$1 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$1 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$2 found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.SuperNotCalledException found in modules fragment-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$ForceLoadContentObserver found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$OnLoadCompleteListener found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$1 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$2 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$3 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$4 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$AsyncTaskResult found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$Status found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$WorkerRunnable found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$BroadcastRecord found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$ReceiverRecord found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTitleStrip found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTitleStrip$PageListener found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$1 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$2 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$ItemInfo found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$LayoutParams found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$PagerObserver found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState$1 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SimpleOnPageChangeListener found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Comment: really, try to use  "code" to post all your logs

Comment: Be specific about your question. You can use the guide for how to ask a question so that it becomes more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate file error comes when you have added the dependency jar to build.gradle file and also you are having same .jar file in your libs folder. To eliminate this error try to have only one thing, either have it in your build.gradle or in locally in your libs folder.